# Recién estoy aprendiendo PrimeFaces y en la parte de Lazy, no sé, ¿Dónde puedo encontrar el ShowcaseUtil.getPropertyValueViaReflection?. Me da error

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces

La parte del código es:

```
 Object columnValue = String.valueOf(ShowcaseUtil.getPropertyValueViaReflection(o, filter.getField()));
```

Lo que no encuentro es el `ShowcaseUtil.getPropertyValueViaReflection`

Ya probé con las dependencias `Showcase` y siempre da error
¿Es posible utilizar otro método?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto:
El código que he utilizado y me funciona es:

```
Object columnValue = String.valueOf(o.getClass().getField(filter.getField()).get(o));
```

Lo encontré en:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790948/how-to-use-filters-in-the-lazydatamodel-in-primefaces-10